# Escape special characters in HTML

Tags: html

I'm wondering whether I can escape special characters in Html without using
Html Number:

```
%#60 = <
%#62 = >
```

I know I need to use %#60 to represent '<' in Html

Is any special tags that can escape all special character?

e.g.

```
<special_tag>
any special characters can be shown without using Html Numbers    
</special_tag>
```

Comment: Perhaps &lt; and &gt; ?

Comment: This is not what i'm looking for. I'm looking for special tags so that I can type some special characters inside the tag and I don't have to use those Html Number or Symbol.

Comment: There used to such elements, but most current browsers don't support them any more. The only way to to escape the characters. You seem to be trying to solve the wrong problem. Why can't you escape your text?

Comment: if you are using PHP, you have function for that, otherwise you have to used "&lt;" (http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_symbols.asp) characters.

Comment: There are lots of reasons. e.g. if you are writing a article on your html file, and you don't have to worry about the those angle brackets, I can use Html Numbers[%lt] but this is hard to read/write. BTW, I did not use any PHP and JavaScript

Comment: @elliptic00 Any reasonable text editor has an HTML escaping function built in, or at least available as a plugin. Or you could use some other script/tool to escape your articles and build HTML files from them.

Comment: The answer without any kind of `PHP` or `JS` is no. But you may want to configure your text editor to replace `>` and others with its equivalent in HTML. For example in `vim` using `abbr > &gt;`.  So when you type `>` it becomes `&gt;`

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in `pre` tag

```
<pre>
    >
</pre>
```